# How to get the value of multivalued parameter in textbox in SSRS

Tags: reportingservices-2005, reporting-services

when the multivalued parameter is selcted how to get the valu in textbox?

eg

my dropdown box is having select all, success,failure

i want to display the above values in textbox..so i have selected the value for text box as Parameters!value.Value(0)

it works if we select only succes or only failure in the drop down box but when we select both i.e, select all the text box value is displaying just success instead of success,failure..

can you please help me with this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got this by using join
Join(Parameters!value.Value, ", ")

Comment: This should probably be marked as the accepted answer; at least for me this was the quick fix I was looking for.